# ANR in dev console, there are no traces to my app

Tags: android, android-anr-dialog

Received below ANR report in my Dev console, but it didn't contains any trace to my app,This report got received only once, so i am not much worried about it, but still curious what can cause this ANR. Any pointers will be appreciated.

```
DALVIK THREADS:
(mutexes: tll=0 tsl=0 tscl=0 ghl=0)

"main" prio=5 tid=1 NATIVE
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40d2f568 self=0x40ce7ab0
| sysTid=354 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1074001456
| schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=47666 stm=8637 core=0
#00 pc 0000da40 /system/lib/libc.so (epoll_wait+12)
#01 pc 00014791 /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollInner(int)+96)
#02 pc 000149f9 /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollOnce(int, int*, int*, void**)+104)
#03 pc 0005d11b /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::NativeMessageQueue::pollOnce(_JNIEnv*, int)+22)
#04 pc 0001de30 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+112)
#05 pc 0004ce73 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+390)
#06 pc 00027260 /system/lib/libdvm.so
#07 pc 0002bb38 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+180)
#08 pc 0005f877 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInvokeMethod(Object*, Method const*, ArrayObject*, ArrayObject*, ClassObject*, bool)+374)
#09 pc 00066d4d /system/lib/libdvm.so
#10 pc 00027260 /system/lib/libdvm.so
#11 pc 0002bb38 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+180)
#12 pc 0005f5b1 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethodV(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, bool, JValue*, std::__va_list)+272)
#13 pc 000494cb /system/lib/libdvm.so
#14 pc 0004698d /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
#15 pc 0004746f /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::start(char const*, char const*)+390)
#16 pc 00000dcf /system/bin/app_process
#17 pc 00016eab /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_init+38)
#18 pc 00000b34 /system/bin/app_process
at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:125)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:124)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

"SystemUI UsbStorageActivity" prio=5 tid=34 NATIVE
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x4198dbc8 self=0x5157b170
| sysTid=16844 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1363754808
| schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=18 stm=30 core=0
#00 pc 0000da40 /system/lib/libc.so (epoll_wait+12)
#01 pc 00014791 /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollInner(int)+96)
#02 pc 000149f9 /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollOnce(int, int*, int*, void**)+104)
#03 pc 0005d11b /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::NativeMessageQueue::pollOnce(_JNIEnv*, int)+22)
#04 pc 0001de30 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+112)
#05 pc 0004ce73 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+390)
#06 pc 00000214 /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted)
at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:125)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:124)
at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)

"SystemUI UsbStorageActivity" prio=5 tid=33 NATIVE
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x419fbec0 self=0x4bf50128
| sysTid=20894 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1362083464
| schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=29 stm=49 core=0
#00 pc 0000da40 /system/lib/libc.so (epoll_wait+12)
#01 pc 00014791 /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollInner(int)+96)
#02 pc 000149f9 /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollOnce(int, int*, int*, void**)+104)
#03 pc 0005d11b /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::NativeMessageQueue::pollOnce(_JNIEnv*, int)+22)
#04 pc 0001de30 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+112)
#05 pc 0004ce73 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+390)
#06 pc 00000214 /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted)
at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:125)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:124)
at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)

"Binder_10" prio=5 tid=32 NATIVE
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x4191ae70 self=0x4c179408
| sysTid=19876 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1364312144
| schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=76 stm=68 core=0
#00 pc 0000cb60 /system/lib/libc.so (__ioctl+8)
#01 pc 00027d4d /system/lib/libc.so (ioctl+16)
#02 pc 00016bfd /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::talkWithDriver(bool)+124)
#03 pc 000173af /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::joinThreadPool(bool)+154)
#04 pc 0001b171 /system/lib/libbinder.so
#05 pc 00010f47 /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+114)
#06 pc 000468bb /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::javaThreadShell(void*)+66)
#07 pc 00010aad /system/lib/libutils.so
#08 pc 00012b90 /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+48)
#09 pc 000122f4 /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+172)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"Binder_F" prio=5 tid=31 NATIVE
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x417f8690 self=0x4dcc2fd8
| sysTid=14287 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1363298248
| schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=80 stm=73 core=0
#00 pc 0000cb60 /system/lib/libc.so (__ioctl+8)
#01 pc 00027d4d /system/lib/libc.so (ioctl+16)
#02 pc 00016bfd /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::talkWithDriver(bool)+124)
#03 pc 000173af /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::joinThreadPool(bool)+154)
#04 pc 0001b171 /system/lib/libbinder.so
#05 pc 00010f47 /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+114)
#06 pc 000468bb /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::javaThreadShell(void*)+66)
#07 pc 00010aad /system/lib/libutils.so
#08 pc 00012b90 /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+48)
#09 pc 000122f4 /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+172)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"Binder_E" prio=5 tid=30 NATIVE
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x41866000 self=0x516a5770
| sysTid=12526 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1365161008
| schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=80 stm=86 core=0
#00 pc 0000cb60 /system/lib/libc.so (__ioctl+8)
#01 pc 00027d4d /system/lib/libc.so (ioctl+16)
#02 pc 00016bfd /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::talkWithDriver(bool)+124)
#03 pc 000173af /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::joinThreadPool(bool)+154)
#04 pc 0001b171 /system/lib/libbinder.so
#05 pc 00010f47 /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+114)
#06 pc 000468bb /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::javaThreadShell(void*)+66)
#07 pc 00010aad /system/lib/libutils.so
#08 pc 00012b90 /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+48)
#09 pc 000122f4 /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+172)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"Binder_D" prio=5 tid=29 NATIVE
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x419f6e28 self=0x4be22280
| sysTid=11060 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1304985112
| schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=82 stm=90 core=0
#00 pc 0000cb60 /system/lib/libc.so (__ioctl+8)
#01 pc 00027d4d /system/lib/libc.so (ioctl+16)
#02 pc 00016bfd /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::talkWithDriver(bool)+124)
#03 pc 000173af /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::joinThreadPool(bool)+154)
#04 pc 0001b171 /system/lib/libbinder.so
#05 pc 00010f47 /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+114)
#06 pc 000468bb /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::javaThreadShell(void*)+66)
#07 pc 00010aad /system/lib/libutils.so
#08 pc 00012b90 /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+48)
#09 pc 000122f4 /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+172)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"Binder_C" prio=5 tid=28 NATIVE
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x4186d168 self=0x4dba0b98
| sysTid=3518 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1363297608
| schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=101 stm=95 core=0
#00 pc 0000cb60 /system/lib/libc.so (__ioctl+8)
#01 pc 00027d4d /system/lib/libc.so (ioctl+16)
#02 pc 00016bfd /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::talkWithDriver(bool)+124)
#03 pc 000173af /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::joinThreadPool(bool)+154)
#04 pc 0001b171 /system/lib/libbinder.so
#05 pc 00010f47 /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+114)
#06 pc 000468bb /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::javaThreadShell(void*)+66)
#07 pc 00010aad /system/lib/libutils.so
#08 pc 00012b90 /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+48)
#09 pc 000122f4 /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+172)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"Binder_B" prio=5 tid=27 NATIVE
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x419eb610 self=0x5135ec40
| sysTid=3229 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1362831816
| schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=91 stm=103 core=0
#00 pc 0000cb60 /system/lib/libc.so (__ioctl+8)
#01 pc 00027d4d /system/lib/libc.so (ioctl+16)
#02 pc 00016bfd /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::talkWithDriver(bool)+124)
#03 pc 000173af /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::joinThreadPool(bool)+154)
#04 pc 0001b171 /system/lib/libbinder.so
#05 pc 00010f47 /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+114)
#06 pc 000468bb /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::javaThreadShell(void*)+66)
#07 pc 00010aad /system/lib/libutils.so
#08 pc 00012b90 /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+48)
#09 pc 000122f4 /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+172)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"Binder_A" prio=5 tid=26 NATIVE
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount...
```

Comment: Anything u found @Akhil? I have similar Issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16838917/anr-in-random-usage-of-application